# Can't enable Wi-Fi on 16.04 - Ralink RT5390

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, ralink

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, but my WiFi has not worked anymore.

When I turn on my ubuntu the system shows me *Wireless network available*, but then the WiFi is switched to **OFF** and I can't switch it to **ON** anymore.

My wireless card is a **Ralink - RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe** as is possible to see below:

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 00
   serial: 84:4b:f5:47:2b:4b
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=0.34 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:f7900000-f790ffff
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I have the same card, where did you find the drivers for it?

Comment: You can find the drivers [here](https://github.com/wapmesquita/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_v2)

But it doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04 only 14.04.

Comment: Yeah I think I already tried compiling this one for mine.  Thanks anyways, maybe I'll just switch back to 14.04.  Though the only reason I want to use the card is for ad hoc connections.  I have the full pcieversion of the card in my desktop

Comment: I have the same wireless card with Ubuntu 16.04 and can't connect either. I filed a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1587674) and the bug has been confirmed. You can report it as also affecting you.